# How can I access the value of a specific button that has the same classes

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I am developing a web app of where the user can search the song lyrics they want. I am using an API for it. Now I can generate 10 songs results, but the problem is when a user click on "get lyrics" button I can not access the value of that specific button's song title. How can I get the specific song title and album name by just clicking the get lyrics button? Here is my final result:

[image: here is my final result]

```js
const apiUrl = "https://api.lyrics.ovh/suggest";
const search = document.getElementById("search-btn");
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const text = document.getElementById("text");
const getLyrics = document.getElementsByClassName("get-lyrics");


//search by songs or artist...
function searchSongs(term) {
    fetch (`${apiUrl}/${term}`)
    .then (response => response.json())
    .then (data => {
        const lyricsName = document.getElementsByClassName("lyrics-name");
        for (let index = 0; index < lyricsName.length; index++) {
            const element = lyricsName[index];
            element.innerText = data.data[index].album.title;
        }

        const artist = document.getElementsByClassName("artist");
        for (let index = 0; index < artist.length; index++) {
            const element = artist[index];
            element.innerText = data.data[index].artist.name;
        }
        document.getElementById("result").style.display = "block";
        //console.log(data);
    });
}


//event listener to search song or artist
search.addEventListener("click", e => {
    //e.preventDefault();
    const searchTerm = text.value;
    if (!searchTerm) {
        alert("please type a song a name");
    } else {
        searchSongs(searchTerm);
    }
})


//event listener to get lyrics
for (let index = 0; index < getLyrics.length; index++) {
    const element = getLyrics[index];
    element.addEventListener("click", function(){
        const title = `${index + 1}`;
       
    })
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Hard Rock Solution - Song Lyric App</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Custom css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar  navbar-dark my-3">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Hard Rock Solution">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavId" aria-controls="collapsibleNavId" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <img src="images/toggler-icon.svg" alt="">
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavId">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdownId" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownId">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 1</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 2</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="content-area">
            <div class="search-bar col-md-6 mx-auto">
                <h1 class="text-center">Lyrics Search</h1>
                <div class="search-box my-5">
                    <input id="text" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your artist song name"> <span id="artist"></span> <span id="title"></span>
                    <button id="search-btn" class="btn btn-success search-btn">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- search results -->
            <div id="result" class="search-result col-md-8 mx-auto py-4">
                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsOne" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistOne" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button id="btnOne" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsTwo" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistTwo" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button id="btnTwo" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsThree" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistThree" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button id="btnThree" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsFour" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistFour" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button id="btnFour" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsFive" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistFive" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button id="btnFive" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsSix" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistSix" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button id="btnSix" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsSeven" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistSeven" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button id="btnSeven" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsEight" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistEight" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button id="btnEight" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsNine" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistNine" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button id="btnNine" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsTen" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistTen" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button id="btnTen" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- === search results === -->

            <!-- Single Lyrics -->
            <div id="lyrics" class="single-lyrics text-center">
                <button class="btn go-back">&lsaquo;</button>
                <h2 class="text-success mb-4">Pentatonix - Na Na Na</h2>
                <pre class="lyric text-white">
                    Wont go whistling like the wind blows,
                    Looking out my window,
                    Just to see the shine
                    Maybe you might call it crazy,
                    How Im acting lately,

                    Skipping through the sky



                    I see so clearly,

                    Why Im always feeling free.

                    So I sleep when my dreams,

                    Looking like reality



                    (Gonna feel it! Na na na...) x4



                    Gonna feel it!



                    I know where the greener grass grows

                    Youll just have to follow

                    To the other side



                    Lets go tiptoe on a tight rope,

                    Fallings only natural

                    Just spread your wings and fly



                    Youll see so clearly,

                    Why Im always feeling free.

                    So I sleep when our dreams

                    Looking like reality



                    (Gonna feel it! Na na na...) x4



                    Bring it down like

                    Ohh way oh

                    Yeah yeah yeah yeah yeah yeah

                    Break it down like

                    Ohh way oh

                    Yeah, yeah, yeah...

                    All around like

                    Ohh way oh

                    Yeah, yeah, yeah...

                    Sing it loud like!

                    Ohh way oh

                    Ah oo oo ooo



                    Gonna feel it! (Na na na...)

                    Make it sound like! (Na na na...)

                    All around like! (Na na na...)

                    Sing it loud like! (Na na na...)

                    Gonna feel like! (Na na na...)
                </pre>
            </div>
        </main>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Script Here -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just combined the 3 for loops into one.

```js
const apiUrl = "https://api.lyrics.ovh/suggest";
const search = document.getElementById("search-btn");
const result = document.getElementById("result");
const text = document.getElementById("text");
const getLyrics = document.getElementsByClassName("get-lyrics");


//search by songs or artist...
function searchSongs(term) {
    fetch (`${apiUrl}/${term}`)
    .then (response => response.json())
    .then (data => {
        const lyricsName = document.getElementsByClassName("lyrics-name");
        const getLyrics = document.getElementsByClassName("get-lyrics ");
        const artist = document.getElementsByClassName("artist");
        for (let index = 0; index < lyricsName.length; index++) {
            lyricsName[index].innerText = data.data[index].album.title;
            artist[index].innerText = data.data[index].artist.name;
          
            //event listener to get lyrics
            getLyrics[index].addEventListener("click", function(){
                    console.log("Song:"+data.data[index].album.title +" By:"+data.data[index].artist.name);
              //getLyricsAPI(title, artist);
            });
            
        }

        document.getElementById("result").style.display = "block";
        //console.log(data);
    });
}


//event listener to search song or artist
search.addEventListener("click", e => {
    //e.preventDefault();
    const searchTerm = text.value;
    if (!searchTerm) {
        alert("please type a song a name");
    } else {
        searchSongs(searchTerm);
    }
})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Hard Rock Solution - Song Lyric App</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Custom css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar  navbar-dark my-3">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Hard Rock Solution">
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavId" aria-controls="collapsibleNavId" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <img src="images/toggler-icon.svg" alt="">
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavId">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdownId" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownId">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 1</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action 2</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="content-area">
            <div class="search-bar col-md-6 mx-auto">
                <h1 class="text-center">Lyrics Search</h1>
                <div class="search-box my-5">
                    <input id="text" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your artist song name"> <span id="artist"></span> <span id="title"></span>
                    <button id="search-btn" class="btn btn-success search-btn">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- search results -->
            <div id="result" class="search-result col-md-8 mx-auto py-4">
                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsOne" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistOne" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button  id="btnOne" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsTwo" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistTwo" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button id="btnTwo" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsThree" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistThree" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button id="btnThree" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsFour" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistFour" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button id="btnFour" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsFive" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistFive" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button id="btnFive" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsSix" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistSix" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button id="btnSix" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsSeven" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistSeven" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button id="btnSeven" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsEight" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistEight" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button id="btnEight" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsNine" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistNine" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button id="btnNine" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="single-result row align-items-center my-3 p-3">
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <h3 id="lyricsTen" class="lyrics-name">Purple Noon</h3>
                        <p id="artistTen" class="author lead">Album by <span class="artist">Washed Out</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 text-md-right text-center">
                        <button id="btnTen" class="get-lyrics btn btn-success">Get Lyrics</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- === search results === -->

            <!-- Single Lyrics -->
            <div id="lyrics" class="single-lyrics text-center">
                <button class="btn go-back">&lsaquo;</button>
                <h2 class="text-success mb-4">Pentatonix - Na Na Na</h2>
                <pre class="lyric text-white">
                    Wont go whistling like the wind blows,
                    Looking out my window,
                    Just to see the shine
                    Maybe you might call it crazy,
                    How Im acting lately,

                    Skipping through the sky



                    I see so clearly,

                    Why Im always feeling free.

                    So I sleep when my dreams,

                    Looking like reality



                    (Gonna feel it! Na na na...) x4



                    Gonna feel it!



                    I know where the greener grass grows

                    Youll just have to follow

                    To the other side



                    Lets go tiptoe on a tight rope,

                    Fallings only natural

                    Just spread your wings and fly



                    Youll see so clearly,

                    Why Im always feeling free.

                    So I sleep when our dreams

                    Looking like reality



                    (Gonna feel it! Na na na...) x4



                    Bring it down like

                    Ohh way oh

                    Yeah yeah yeah yeah yeah yeah

                    Break it down like

                    Ohh way oh

                    Yeah, yeah, yeah...

                    All around like

                    Ohh way oh

                    Yeah, yeah, yeah...

                    Sing it loud like!

                    Ohh way oh

                    Ah oo oo ooo



                    Gonna feel it! (Na na na...)

                    Make it sound like! (Na na na...)

                    All around like! (Na na na...)

                    Sing it loud like! (Na na na...)

                    Gonna feel like! (Na na na...)
                </pre>
            </div>
        </main>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Script Here -->

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code (edited version) works perfectly. Thank you very much. I just have a question. When i am using  your code (original version) it is just giving me the result of the final element (10th item). But when using your edited version code then it works perfectly fine.  What is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the event object into your event listener so you will get the which element is clicked. In event listener you can check element's id or what attribute you want to look. If you change the ids of buttons you will get the song information from the buttons.

```
for (let index = 0; index < getLyrics.length; index++) {
    const element = getLyrics[index];
    element.addEventListener("click", function(event){
        console.log(event.target.getAttribute('id'))
        const title = `${index + 1}`;
       
    })
}
```